# Uncaught ReferenceError: $each is not defined in jQuery AJAX Success Callback

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm facing an issue in my jQuery AJAX success callback where I receive an "Uncaught ReferenceError: $each is not defined" error. The goal is to iterate through the result array using $.each, but it seems there's a problem with jQuery.
Code:

HTML (FilteredAddressDetails.cshtml):

```
@model AmarisPrint.Models.FilteredAddressDetailsViewModel

<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" /> <title>Filtered Address Details</title>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js"></script>

<script src="~/Scripts/FilteredAddressDetails.js"></script>

</head> <body>


<div>
    <label for="selectedDate">Select Date</label>
    @Html.TextBox("selectedDate", Model.SelectedDate.HasValue ? Model.SelectedDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") : "", new { type = "date" })
    <button id="getResultsBtn">Get Results</button>
</div>

<div id="filteredDataContainer" style="display: none;">
    <table id="filteredDataTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Student Name</th>
                <th>Parent Name</th>
                <th>Address</th>
                <th>Pin Code</th>
                <th>Mobile</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Timestamp</th>
                <th>Order No</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <p id="noDataMessage" style="display: none;">No data found for the selected date.</p>
</div>
```

</body>
</html>

JavaScript (FilteredAddressDetails.js):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
$("#getResultsBtn").click(function () {
var selectedDate = $("#selectedDate").val();

 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Home/FilteredAddressDetails",
        data: { selectedDate: selectedDate },
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);  

            $.each(result, function (index, item) {
                var row = '<tr>' +
                    '<td>' + item.OrderNo + '</td>' +
                    '<td>' + item.StudentName + '</td>' +
                    '<td>' + item.ParentName + '</td>' +
                    '<td>' + item.Address + '</td>' +
                    '<td>' + item.PinCode + '</td>' +
                    '<td>' + item.Mobile + '</td>' +
                    '<td>' + item.Email + '</td>' +
                    '<td>' + item.TimeStamp + '</td>' +
                   
                    '</tr>';
                $('#filteredDataTable tbody').append(row);
            });

            $("#filteredDataContainer").show();
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log("Error:", error);
        }
    });
});
```

});

C# (FilteredAddressDetailsController.cs):

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult FilteredAddressDetails()
{
    var model = new FilteredAddressDetailsViewModel();
    return View(model);
}

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult FilteredAddressDetails(string selectedDate)
        {
            if (DateTime.TryParseExact(selectedDate, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime parsedDate))
            {
                var filteredData = _db.AddressDetails
     .Where(ad => System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.TruncateTime(ad.TimeStamp) == parsedDate.Date)
     .Join(_db.Orders,
         ad => ad.OrderId,
         o => o.Id,
         (ad, o) => new AddressDetailsViewModel
         {
             StudentName = ad.StudentName,
             ParentName = ad.ParentName,
             Address = ad.Address,
             PinCode = ad.PinCode,
             Mobile = ad.Mobile,
             Email = ad.Email,
             TimeStamp = ad.TimeStamp,
             OrderNo = o.OrderNo
         })
     .ToList();


                var viewModel = new FilteredAddressDetailsViewModel
                {
                    SelectedDate = parsedDate,
                    FilteredData = filteredData
                };

                return View(viewModel);
            }

            return View();
        }
    }
Model class(.cs)

      public class FilteredAddressDetailsViewModel
      {
     public DateTime? SelectedDate { get; set; }
     public List<AddressDetailsViewModel> FilteredData { get; set; }
     }

   public class AddressDetailsViewModel
 {
     public string StudentName { get; set; }
     public string ParentName { get; set; }
     public string Address { get; set; }
     public string PinCode { get; set; }
     public string Mobile { get; set; }
     public string Email { get; set; }
     public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
     public string OrderNo { get; set; }
 }
```

Steps to Reproduce:

Enter a date in the input field.
Click the "Get Results" button.
Observe the error in the browser console.
What I've Tried:

I have already tried replacing $each with jQuery.each.
Confirming that jQuery is loaded successfully before the script.
Checking for any jQuery conflicts.
Expected Behavior:
I expect the AJAX success callback to iterate through the result array using $.each without any errors, appending rows to the table.
`your text`
Actual Behavior:
I'm encountering the "Uncaught ReferenceError: $each is not defined" error in the browser console.

Comment: I've untagged SQL Server and C# as they appear to have nothing to do with the issue you are facing.

Comment: From what I can tell without fixing the layout of your code is that the POST action returns a `View()` which should be HTML  - so `console.log(result);` will be HTML, not JSON.  I would expect the POST action to return a `PartialView(model)` then the cshtml could format your table and it would be a simple case of `$("#filteredDataContainer").html(html)` - if you want to build the HTML in the js instead of taking advantage of PartialViews then return JSON.   We'd need to see an example of `result` to tell exactly what the issue is.

Comment: Your script references should go at the bottom of your CSHTML file, by the way.